# How to delete from firebase realtime database use python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase realtime database in Python, and have structure data like this:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "-LuOXedSsg_1vZ9WBePA" : {
      "name" : "Adam",
      "password" : "adam",
      "username" : "adam"
    },
    "-LuOXk-fE99ucZbrlBk_" : {
      "name" : "Joi",
      "password" : "joi",
      "username" : "joi"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to delete the **child("-LuOXk-fE99ucZbrlBk_")** with this code:

```
# input
username_to_delete = input ("username:")

data = ref.get()

for key,val in data.items():
    if (username_to_delete == val['username']):
        delete_user_ref = ref.child(key)
        delete_user_ref.set(None)
    else:
        print(usernameDoesNotExist)
```

I want to delete the child by setting it as **NULL** (**None** in Python), but when it starts and input the correct **username**, I get an error like this:

```
in set
     raise ValueError ('Value must not be None.')
ValueError: Value must not be None.
```

what should i do? i am still new in firebase and python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `delete()` method:

```
delete_user_ref.delete()
```

For reference check the following docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db

> set(value)
>   Sets the data at this location to the given value.
>
> The value must be JSON-serializable and not None.
>
> Parameters:
>   value – JSON-serializable value to be set at this location.
>
> Raises:
>   ValueError – If the provided value is None.
>   TypeError – If the value is not JSON-serializable.
>   FirebaseError – If an error occurs while communicating with the remote database server.

Comment: Initially I thought by setting Child to **NULL** ( **None** in python ) it would delete the users, but it didn't. and hey I'm very grateful because now I can delete users by using the ```delete()``` method. @PeterHaddad